# Java JSONObject is unquoted when receiving it in Node,js app

Tags: java, json, node.js, parsing, socket.io

I am using Socket.IO between an Android app, and a Node.js API.
I need to serialize some objects, so I have to use JSONObject in my Android app.

The problem is that when receiving each object server-side, the JSON data is unparsable, because the "value" are missing quotes on their names.

**Client :**

```
obj = new JSONObject(); 

obj.put("lon", 2.1459905000000004);
obj.put("lat", 48.8367079);
```

**Server :**

```
socket.on('position_changed', function(data, reply) {

    console.log(data);
    // Outputs { lon: 2.1459905000000004, lat: 48.8367079 }
    // Expected { "lon": 2.1459905000000004, "lat": 48.8367079 }

    try {
        newPosition = JSON.parse(data);
    }   catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Isn't it already parsed? Try `console.log(typeof data)` if it outputs `object` then it's already parsed.

Comment: @victorkohl You are right. That was the problem. I didn't know Socket.IO would automatically parse my object.

Comment: @victorkohl, I will post the full code, please post your answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The JSON sent to the NodeJS app is probably already parsed.

You can confirm it by checking its type:

```
console.log(typeof data);
```

If the output is `object` then it's already parsed.

Comment: As you said, data is already a parsed JSON object. Do you know how to handle the case of when the client sends malformed JSON ?
Would you think that checking if `data`'s type is an object would be a good practice to ensure that JSON is OK ?

Comment: @MalteseFalcon I don't have enough experience with SocketIO but yes, you could check the `data`'s type before performing any actions on it. If a malformed JSON is sent, you probably will have a string as `data` or an exception is thrown somewhere and you will have to handle this scenario.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I did for the moment.
`if (!newPosition || typeof newPosition !== 'object') { ... }`